# Serving multiple TLDs from one Rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, passenger

I currently have a single machine, running a stack that includes nginx/Passenger/Rails 3.x.  This machine has several IP addresses, one for each TLD we're serving, primarily for SSL certificate purposes.

I'm having an issue with longer TLDs (.co.uk, .com.au, and their ilk.) My first attempt was the following filter in my ApplicationController:

```
if request.host =~ /co\.uk$|com\.au$/
  ActionDispatch::Http::URL.tld_length = 2
else
  ActionDispatch::Http::URL.tld_length = 1
end
```

Unfortunately, this runs *after* the routes have already been parsed, which means my subdomain handling in the config/routes.rb is already finished (and wrong). But, rather dangerously, I'm permanently affecting this passenger instance for the NEXT request. So it's breaking not only on this request for .com.au, but probably the next request for .com as well.

I have a feeling that what I should be doing is setting `tld_length` in my environment file, but I'd need to do it based on the IP address of the interface the user has connected to (since I have a different IP address for each TLD).

Is there an easy way to do this? If not, is there a better way to handle multiple TLDs on the same machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like middleware is the way to go.  Here's the solution that ended up working for me.

```
# config/application.rb

config.middleware.use TldHandler
```

And:

```
# app/lib/tld_handler.rb
class TldHandler
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    TldHandler.enable_long_tlds(env['SERVER_NAME'])
    status, headers, response = @app.call(env)
  end

  def self.enable_long_tlds(hostname)
    if hostname =~ /co\.uk$|com\.au$/
      ActionDispatch::Http::URL.tld_length = 2
    else
      ActionDispatch::Http::URL.tld_length = 1
    end
  end
end
```

You could continue to expand the regex as desired.